# flat tables no meta title

Tags: magento-1.9, eav, flat-catalog

Does anyone know why meta_title attribute is missing both for product and category flat tables?

I can see meta_description and meta_keyword fields in the flat tables but no meta_title. So I am forced to use eav model, which is fine. But I was wondering why is this so. Also does anyone has a "fix" for this in order to add meta_title to the flat tables?

Comment: Open attribute in admin, set "Use in product listing" as Yes, and then try re-indexing.

Comment: @Prateek please post this as an answer, I will give it a try and if this works I will accept your answer since is the most simple thing to do IMHO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open 'meta_title' attribute in admin, set "Use in product listing" as Yes, and then try re-indexing. AFAIK, Only attributes selected to be "Used in Product Listing" get included in flat tables.

Comment: This method will only work for product_flat but not for category_flat tables, do you know if is possible to do the same for categories? Maybe with a sql update to set this value for the category attribute?

Comment: For categories, it should be pulled automatically. Take a look at class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat`. It takes all attributes while creating flat tables for categories in a store. I have a stock installation and I can see 'meta_title' in the columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding `meta_title` attribute at `frontend/product/collection/attributes` node at config.xml

```
<frontend>
     <product>
         <collection>
             <attributes>
                 <meta_title/>
             </attributes>
         </collection>
     </product>
</frontend>
```

### Explanation:

**Let explain:**

First look at class [`Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer`](https://github.com/engineyard/magento-ce-1.9/blob/master/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php) .

and a function name `getAttributeCodes()` which responsible  for   columns creation at `catalog product flat`.

Magento is first take  the attributse from `global/catalog/product/flat/attribute_nodes`  using

**Mage::getConfig() ->getNode(self::XML_NODE_ATTRIBUTE_NODES)
                ->children();**

from [`config.xml`](https://github.com/engineyard/magento-ce-1.9/blob/master/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml) at `app/code/core/Mage_Catalog/etc/`

```
 <flat>
                    <max_index_count>64</max_index_count>
                    <attribute_nodes>
                        <product_collection>frontend/product/collection/attributes</product_collection>
                    </attribute_nodes>
                    <add_filterable_attributes>0</add_filterable_attributes>
                    <add_child_data>0</add_child_data>
                    <flag>
                        <model>catalog/product_flat_flag</model>
                    </flag>
                </flat>
```

Which  internally call **config node**: `frontend/product/collection/attributes`.

If we define an attribute here then this attribute will automatically  added as columns in `flat table`.

```
 <frontend>
        <product>
            <collection>
                <attributes>
                      <attribute_Code/>
                </attributes>
            </collection>
        </product>
    </frontend>
```

Then need to product flat index form index management.